# SharePoint 2010 SP1 - Set permissions error

Tags: 2010, permissions, error, service-pack, inheritance

I updated my SharePoint 2010 (Language: German) environment with SP1.
After the update I had the problem that when I want to create a (Website/Blog/Forum etc. but not Documentlibrary/List etc.) with broken inheritance a exception is thrown at the configuration from the permissions (Picture). This error concerns only the configuration from the permissions, the object was created.

I think this problem is not at english language systems. (Because my en-us virtualmachine had this problem not, but my de-de (German) virtualmachine too)

Is that issue also at systems with other language packs?

Anybody knows a solution to solve this problem?

[image]

**ULS Log:**

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    77a3    Verbose Starting correlation. Transfer from 84dbe0e7-476b-44fa-946c-254e80997dc5

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (POST:http://test-mysharepoint.de.de:80/websites/9999/TestTeamwebsite5/_layouts/permsetup.aspx?HideCancel=1&NextUsing=http%3A%2F%2Ftest-mysharepoint.de.de%2Fwebsites%2F9999%2FTestTeamwebsite5)

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Foundation   SQM 97qu    Verbose SQM: Datapoint id 6693 marked as Increment datapoint.

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  User=test\user

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/websites/9999

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Server   Logging Correlation Data    9gc5    Verbose Thread change; resetting trace level override to 0; resetting correlation to 852e64e8-ef80-47da-b295-1559355b35df 84dbe0e7-476b-44fa-946c-254e80997dc5

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Server   General 0   Verbose Looking for a cached value matching 399e6469-e588-4997-9c30-28e337273317 in the Profile Property Cache cache.

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Server   General 0   Verbose Cache hit.

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Server   General 0   Verbose Looking for a cached value matching 399e6469-e588-4997-9c30-28e337273317 in the Profile Property Cache cache.

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Server   General 0   Verbose Cache hit.

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Server   General 0   Verbose Looking for a cached value matching 399e6469-e588-4997-9c30-28e337273317 in the Profile Property Cache cache.

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Server   General 0   Verbose Cache hit.

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Server   General 0   Verbose Looking for a cached value matching 399e6469-e588-4997-9c30-28e337273317 in the Profile Property Cache cache.

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Server   General 0   Verbose Cache hit.

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Server   Taxonomy    cn12    Verbose Begin: constructor TaxonomySession.TaxonomySession

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Server   Taxonomy    cn13    Verbose End: constructor TaxonomySession.TaxonomySession

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Server   General 0   Verbose Looking for a cached value matching 399e6469-e588-4997-9c30-28e337273317 in the Profile Property Cache cache.

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Server   General 0   Verbose Cache hit.

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Foundation   Runtime tkau    Unexpected  System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.    at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.EntityEditor.ParseSpanData(String spans)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.EntityEditor.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection values)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Server   Unified Logging Service cn4g    Verbose Trace level override is turned off.

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://test-mysharepoint.de.de:80/websites/9999/TestTeamwebsite5/_layouts/permsetup.aspx?HideCancel=1&NextUsing=http%3A%2F%2Ftest-mysharepoint.de.de%2Fwebsites%2F9999%2FTestTeamwebsite5)). Ausführungszeit=46,7819234008792

w3wp.exe (0x0820)   0x0D10  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    77a3    Verbose Ending correlation. Transfer to 84dbe0e7-476b-44fa-946c-254e80997dc5

Comment: Update your post with the actual Exception and relevant excerpt from the ULS trace logs.

Comment: I added the ULS logs

Comment: I also have the same problem. On a system without sp1 installed everything works fine. Does the august 2011 CU fix the problem?

Comment: Which language are you using? And whats your CU level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug from SP1 in the internal InputFormCheckBox and InputFormRadioButton. If you are using them, you will get same error message in the logs.

Comment: Do you have any references you could include in your answer?

Comment: It is fixed in CU August